# How to create a drop down list where a date value is shown as a relative date string?

Tags: excel

How do I create a drop down list in Excel so that a value such as `19/02/2017` appears as `Today`?
I want the list to appear as `Today, 06/02, 08/04`, but it's shown as `19/02, 06/02, 08/04`.
`Today` must represent today, for use in other formulas.

Comment: Show us what you have tried to solve this problem, and where you have run into problems.  Depending on how you have set things up, I suspect you might be able to do this with a simple `IF` formula in your list. Also **please** read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: How are you getting your data validation list now?

Comment: I am a very amateur programmer, so I didn't know that apart from data validation, I could use other ways. By the way, I am using data validation. I do not know how to upload any files apart from images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a data validation on a range of formulas like `=IF(A1=TODAY(),"Today",A1)`:

[image]

You can not have 'Today' as text in the list and also as its value to use in formulas, but you can infer 'Today' in the rest of formulas. This is a sample:
`=IF(C1="Today",TODAY(),C1)`

Comment: This will be the accepted answer for now, but please review my changes above.

Comment: Okay, so does that mean I will have to use a `IF()` function?

Comment: You have to interpret 'Today' in your formulas, in same cases it will be an IF like in my sample, but depends by each formula in particular.